# Anchor - Manually setting program account discriminator

Tags: anchor, pda, initialize

Is it possible to set the 8-byte discriminator on an Anchor account manually?

I'm trying to initialize a new pda account in an instruction, but not all of the seeds are available in the context (can't use `instruction(...)` macro to get seed either). I still want to initialize the account as an Anchor `#[account]` though, so that I can access it in subsequent instructions.

Basic program setup:

```
#[account]
pub struct MyAccount {...}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitIx<'info> {
  ...
  #[account(mut)]
  pub my_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
  ...
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitIxWrapper<'info> {
  ...
  init_ix: InitIx<'info>,
  some_pubkey: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
  ...
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct OtherIx<'info> {
  ...
  my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
  ...
}

// The global instruction
pub fn init_ix_wrapper(ctx: Context<InitIxWrapper>) -> Result<()> {
  ...
  // local ix for processing
  local::inix_ix(
    Context::new(
     ...
     ctx.accounts.init_ix,
     ...
    ),
    ctx.accounts.some_pubkey.key
  )?;
  ...
}

pub fn other_ix(ctx: Context<OtherIx>) -> Result<()> {
  // access data from my_account like usual
}
```

I would like the local ix to do something like the following:

```
pub fn init_ix(ctx: Context<InitIx>, my_account_seed: &Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
  // assert derivation of my_account key using my_account_seed
  // manually initialize account (solana create_account ix)
  // manually set discriminator for MyAccount and write to my_account.data
  // write relevant remaining data to my_account.data
}
```

If manually setting discriminator is not possible, then can someone please direct me to a different way to accomplish what I want given my program structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have an account like this:

```
#[account]
pub struct State {}
```

then you can call the discriminator static method like `&State::discriminator()` by importing the trait manually like `use anchor_lang::Discriminator;`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly answering your question but there is a Discriminator trait you can implement.

Comment: It seems that the `#[account]` attribute already implements the `Discriminator` trait. Do you know how to call the `discriminator()` function for a specific account?

Answer (score 1):

As hana said, you can get the discriminator for an account using `MyAccount::discriminator();` so long as you import `anchor_lang::Discriminator` into your source file.

Then you can write the account data like so:

```
let my_account_data = MyAccount {...};
let discriminator = MyAccount::discriminator();
let write_data = (discriminator, my_account_data.clone());
write_data.serialize(&mut *ctx.accounts.my_account.try_borrow_mut_data()?)?;
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: No, you can't, but you can derive the discriminator if you know the function/state name, which is usually good enough.

The discriminator is the first 8 bytes of the sha256 hash of the context and the struct name in the format "namespace:name", in snake_case. Same thing for functions. You can use any sha256 generation tool or get it like so:

```
pub fn get_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);
    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
            [..8],
    );
    sighash
}
```

Where the namespace for your struct is probably "state" or "global".

So you COULD try different names (or rename the context the function is in) until you get a certain discriminator, but it will take a very long time to brute force a collision for the first 8 bytes of sha256 since it's essentially completely random.

It sounds like the function above should work for you, since you can derive the discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

You'd first have to bring the `Discriminator` trait into scope with `use anchor_lang::Discriminator;`

Then your code would be:

```
let discriminator = MyAccount::discriminator();
discriminator.serialize(&mut &mut my_account_info.data.borrow_mut()[..8])?;
```

where `MyAccount` is your Anchor-defined data structure